# GridLayoutManager setSpanSizeLookup creating blank cells

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

currently I'm exploring more on RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager and trying to achieve a nice looking UI for gallery display but I'm having some trouble with the span size of the GridLayoutManager. As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) said:
*By default, each item occupies 1 span. You can change it by providing a custom GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup instance via setSpanSizeLookup(SpanSizeLookup).*

With this I expect that if I set the span to 2 of the item in position 0 it will set the colspan and the rowspan to 2 as well but it seems that it doesn't work that way. I set my column count into 2 for my GridLayoutManager for portrait and 4 for landscape. It works perfectly for portrait but not in landscape as it creates 2 empty cells below the 2nd and 3rd item in which I guess that the 1st item doesn't get the rowspan of 2 or else it really leaves an empty cells.

Here's my code:

```
gallery = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        adapter = new GalleryAdapter(getBaseContext(), gallery);

        // using grid layout manager
        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.col_count));

        mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch(adapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                    case 2:
                        return 2;
                    case 1:
                        return 1;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });

        list_news.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        list_news.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The Adapter:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> article;
    ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return article.size();
    }

    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> article){
        this.context = context;
        this.article = article;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.articles_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        if(position==0){
            return 2;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        mImageLoader = VolleyQueue.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        holder.image.setImageUrl(article.get(position).get("image"), mImageLoader);
        holder.image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.test);
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.image) NetworkImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }



}
}
```

And here's the result screenshot for landscape and portrait:

[image: lanscape]

[image: portrait]

is there's any way I can avoid having blank cells for this?

UPDATE:

to better visualize on what I'm trying to achieve here's an image of what I would want the landscape mode to be. The numbers are the items based on the expected position.

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 2):

Change your `SpanSizeLookup` code into

```
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return adapter.getItemViewType(position);
    }
});
```

And your adapter's `getItemViewType` code into

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.col_count);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh apologies but I need my item 1 to have 2 columns even if I have 4 and just fill the blank cells to make it even. see reference for landscape on what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ok. Let me clarify. So, your question is how to make the yellow and red box in your reference to have the same height as the green box. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No I need it to fill the blank space on bottom of yellow and red box on landscape mode.

Comment: Ok. Now, what are you expecting to go below the yellow and red box?

Comment: If you don't mind, could you update your question with the layout that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Probably you should try using [AsymmetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView)

Comment: But that would be using the AsymmetricGridView and not the RecyclerView which I wanted to implement. Anyways, never knew that it already has a 2.0 version which is kind of good. I've already used this library before. :))

*edit: Just reading about the recyclerview support. Thanks